# Android app crashes with "Error inflating class Button"

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I just have a normal Button view in my Schedule activity from where I go to another activity and update the fields and make API call, but to go there onClick I get unexplainable error. How can I understand the code and the error?

**UpdateSchedule.class**

```
public class UpdateSchedule extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnAddRoute, btnAddSource, btnRouteInfo, btnScheduleInfo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_update_schedule);

        initViews();
    }
```

**activity_update_schedule.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".activity.UpdateSchedule">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/wave__1_"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_route"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:text="Add Route" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Add Halt"
        android:id="@+id/add_source"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/btn_route_info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="add route info" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_schedule_info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="add schedule info" />

    <!--    <FrameLayout-->
<!--        android:id="@+id/frameLayout_schedule_container"-->
<!--        android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
<!--        android:layout_height="match_parent" />-->


</LinearLayout>
```

this is my logs error that is throwing me

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.sts_admin, PID: 30636
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sts_admin/com.example.sts_admin.activity.UpdateSchedule}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25 in com.example.sts_admin:layout/activity_update_schedule: Binary XML file line #25 in com.example.sts_admin:layout/activity_update_schedule: Error inflating class Button
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3846)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4022)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2336)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8653)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25 in com.example.sts_admin:layout/activity_update_schedule: Binary XML file line #25 in com.example.sts_admin:layout/activity_update_schedule: Error inflating class Button
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25 in com.example.sts_admin:layout/activity_update_schedule: Error inflating class Button
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/color/mtrl_btn_text_color_selector.xml from ComplexColor resource ID #0x7f0602a7
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadComplexColorForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:1421)
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadComplexColorFromName(ResourcesImpl.java:1247)
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadColorStateList(ResourcesImpl.java:1326)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:1249)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:600)
    at android.widget.TextView.readTextAppearance(TextView.java:4326)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1360)
    at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:174)
    at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:149)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:81)
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.<init>(MaterialButton.java:228)
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.<init>(MaterialButton.java:224)
    at com.google.android.material.theme.MaterialComponentsViewInflater.createButton(MaterialComponentsViewInflater.java:43)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:156)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1678)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1729)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1059)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:995)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:775)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:197)
    at com.example.sts_admin.activity.UpdateSchedule.onCreate(UpdateSchedule.java:25)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8207) 2023-06-05 14:27:22.679 30636-30636 AndroidRuntime          com.example.sts_admin E   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8191)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3819)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4022)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2336)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8653)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert value at index 0 to color: type=0x1
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:533)
    at android.content.res.ColorStateList.inflate(ColorStateList.java:332)
    at android.content.res.ColorStateList.createFromXmlInner(ColorStateList.java:280)
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadComplexColorForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:1414)
    ... 41 more
```

Comment: Have you try to clean and rebuild your project ?

Comment: Yes I tried to clean the project and rebuild, it kept on coming after that also.

Comment: The issue was with AndroidX compact Button that was put but not initialized in the code to make it accessible.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your issue: (ofc would help to see what initViews() does)

```
public class UpdateSchedule extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnAddRoute, btnAddSource, btnRouteInfo, btnScheduleInfo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_update_schedule);

        btnAddRoute = findViewById(R.id.add_route);
        // do it for all buttons

        initViews();
    }
```